# How I can Redirect to the Login when user Click on Cancel Button.?

Tags: wpf, facebook-login

I am working on WPF app and I am using Oauth 2.0 through the WebBrowserControl there is a bug in WPF WebBrowser Control for getting AccessToken but I can use the Winform WebBrowser and achieve this but once I click on Cancel then it say Success so instead of success I want to Redirect to the again Login so how I can do this my URL is like this.

[FacebookLoginLink](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=popup&scope=user_about_me,offline_access&client_id=231343260264549&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html)

Thank you..!!

Comment: Got the same bug, when tried to use WebBrowserControl with vk.com. Have you reported about it to WPF developers team?